# How to add google analytics to wordpress hosted blog (no access to html)

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have a blog in a basic-plan wordpress account. That means i dont have access to html or any plugins.

How I can I add google analytics script in my blog? Can I just export the blog, add the script and then import the blog back to wordpress? Will I loose any content (post, comments) If I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You are unable to add Javascript code to a Wordpress.com blog.](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/)

As Google Analytics requires Javascript, this means you can't add it to pages or posts. If you want to use it with a Wordpress.com blog, you need to upgrade to the business plan, which [offers this feature](https://en.support.wordpress.com/google-analytics/). Alternatively you could rent some cheap hosting, and install a copy of Wordpress. There you would have the freedom to run whatever code you want.

Comment: Cheers James! I guess I ll rent another host